# Questions with assertions which deviate from Buddhism or Buddhist History

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

[Here is a question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2575/which-buddhist-council-included-the-conclusions-that-there-is-no-creator-god-and) which deviates makes an assertion which is not true regarding both Buddhism and its History. What is the best cause of action to take in such an instance.

Ideally we should try to point the person and would be readers to the right direction and try to attach them to the [Noble Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_Eightfold_Path). So the action needs to be motivational than just up and down voting as this does not give such incentive, guidance or direction. This does not by all means imply we should not use this as a tool to keep the site quality up, but make this and opportunity to cultivate the quality of ['Anuththaro Purisa Dhamma Sarathi'](http://www.thebuddhism.net/2012/08/17/qualities-of-the-triple-gem/) and Skills in Questions.

Comment: What I am looking for is what is the best way to give proper guidance and direction with a view to attach them to the path so that the poster and the readers would get most value addition.

Answer (score 3):

If someone makes a false assumption in his/her question then it's best to point out why the assumption is wrong in a comment. This way the OP can try to salvage the question. If the question is still answerable, despite the false assumption then you can also explain why the assumption is wrong in an answer.

If the false assumption causes the question to be totally irrelevant or unanswerable then it's best to also vote to close it. However, I do think we should make an exception for common misunderstandings (e.g. all buddhists are pacifists) and not close those questions. This way future readers are informed before they ask the same false question, or if they still do ask it (because they didn't find the original question) we can close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: This sounds more reasonable. But instead of closing why not gently point out it's irrelevance and this can be example for other who might have similar throughs.

Comment: @SumindaSirinathSalpitikorala First of all, we want high-quality questions (and answers) here. If we have many low quality questions on the site we risk scaring the expert people away. Second, if you don't close the question then people that have the same false assumption may try to answer it, which most likely results in vote downs and/or big discussions.

Comment: The scary part if people with false assumptions trying to answer it.

Comment: I think best is to protect them some not every one can answer them.

Answer (score 1):

Vote down incoherent questions or fail to vote them up.

Do the same for low quality answers.

Comment: This might not be the most helpful way to point them to the right direction.

Comment: When someone is wrong on the internet, there is only so much we can do about it.

Comment: Yes I agree, but you should give your best try. Otherwise you lose your value system.